# data type for high non-decimal prices

Tags: mysql, types

I've found a lot of questions there and in the other sites about the best data type for storing prices in MySQL and they said `Decimal` is the best.

But, my price column is a bit difference. All prices are integer (non-decimal) and the maximum amount is 999,999,999 ........

Which data type should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your prices are always positive, use `UNSIGNED INT`. It has a range of up to 4 billion (more than enough for you) and stores integer values without loss of precision.

**Related**

- [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html)